# Count distinct with repeating entries over time

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

this is my first stackoverflow question so please be gentle ;-)

I have a table with unique customerIDs and a table including their transactions with a certain transaction type (purchase, presell etc.)

What I want to count is all customers that have done a specific transaction type once. But if a customer has made an eligible transaction in 2014 I dont want this customer to be counted in 2015 again. Does that make sense?

I tried the following statement:

```
SELECT

datepart(yyyy,t.TransactionDate)
,count(DISTINCT c.customerID)

FROM Customers as c

   JOIN Transactions as t
   ON c.CustomerID = t.CustomerID

WHERE t.TransactionType = 'presell'
GROUP BY datepart(yyyy,t.TransactionDate)
```

The issue is that, of course, a customer can do the same transactiontype once a year. So with this statement I count the customers distinct per year...and not just once in total.

**EDIT:** Lets make it a bit easier. There is only one table and that table looks a bit like this:

[image: CustomerTable]

So if I'm filtering for "Presell" my result should look a bit like this

[image]

in 2014 Customer A made a presell, in 2015 customer B made a presell, in 2016 customer A made a presell again but I don't count this customer because I already counted it in 2014. Hope that make things a bit clearer.

Thanks for any advice and help here.

Comment: When you say: "But if a customer has made an eligible transaction in 2014", do you mean that you only want to count the eligible transactions that are at 2 years apart? Please elaborate

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. When asking a SQL question you're most likely to get a good response if you include table structures, sample data, and expected output given that sample data along with any attempts that you've made and how they aren't working (returning wrong data, gives an error, etc). Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: As Tom H said, if you cold include examples of the 2 tables, and also an example of the type of result you expect from your query, this would help a lot :)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the advice. I edited my original question. Maybe that helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you look at it, it is the first presell per customer you are interested in. You can get that easily by selecting `MIN(TransactionDate)` per customer. Once you've done this, you can count.

```
select year, count(*)
from
(
  select customerid, min(transactiondate) as year
  from transactions
  where transactiontype = 'Presell'
  group by customerid
) first_presells
group by year
order by year;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to count `Customers` by `TransactionType`, you should be grouping by `CustomerID` and `TransactionType`, not the `TransactionDate`:

```
SELECT  datepart(yyyy,t.TransactionDate) -- this part won't work anymore without grouping it. Doesn't seem to be relevant to what you're selecting
    ,count(DISTINCT c.customerID)

FROM Customers as c

   JOIN Transactions as t
   ON c.CustomerID = t.CustomerID

WHERE t.TransactionType = 'presell'
GROUP BY c.CustomerID, t.TransactionType
```

This should return the count of people who have completed a transaction of type at least once, regardless of the year.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
SELECT  datepart(yyyy,t.TransactionDate) ,
count(*) over (partition by c.CustomerID, t.TransactionType)

FROM Customers as c

   JOIN Transactions as t
   ON c.CustomerID = t.CustomerID

WHERE t.TransactionType = 'presell'
```

You can have a look at http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-sever-2005-using-over-with-aggregate-functions for more information about aggregate functions like this one.